# Google App Script User Scope Approval for new scope

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I've added the `script.external_request` scope to my GMail Add-on so that I can connect to and store information in a MySQL dB.

The scope was submitted and approved by Google OAuth and Marketplace SDK.

If I run the script in the editor from the HEAD deployment, I get the OAuth approval workflow and the script connects to the database.

In the deployed version I keep getting the following error:

`You do not have permission to call Jdbc.getConnection. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request`

It seems to me that the end users are not getting a trigger to accept the new scope from the UI of the addon.

Is there a way to force the OAuth workflow re-authorization from the addon UI?

Or is there something else going on here?

**ADDED INFO**

I used Aaron's suggestion on the QuickStart to add a logging check to see if the required permissions are present. At least this will point to if this might be a red-herring.

```
    if (authInfo.getAuthorizationStatus() ==
    ScriptApp.AuthorizationStatus.REQUIRED) {
        Logger.log(`${user} - Missing required scope authorizations`)
    }else{
        Logger.log(`${user} - Required scope authorizations present`)
    }
```

Naturally in the 12hrs this has been present, no user has opened the app. So will have to report back later.

Also adding my appscript.json manifest

```
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "GMailAddOn",
      "logoUrl": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/...",
      "layoutProperties": {
        "primaryColor": "#2772ed"
      },
      "useLocaleFromApp": true
    },
    "gmail": {
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "enabled": true,
        "runFunction": "initApp"
      }
    }
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.locale",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"
  ],
  "urlFetchWhitelist": [
    "https://google.com/"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you update the deployment version to the latest version?

Comment: Yes. I did Deploy -> Manage Deployments -> New Version -> and incremented my version #. I know that the code deployed, because I've included some logging statements that I can see active in the logs post deployment.

Comment: How is the add-on executed by the user?  Through some UI element? Or is it run on a trigger that doesn't require user interaction, like a timed trigger?  If the latter, see [this quickstart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/editors/forms/quickstart/forms-notifications) for one way to detect if they haven't authorized and send a notification with a manual auth link.

Comment: Addon has two components, UI elements and a timed trigger. I am only concerned with this function executing within the UI elements. So the user has to launch the addon UI to trigger this function. Thanks for the reference, I haven't seen this doc, so I'll research it to see if it has anything to help solve my issue.

Comment: Another thought: did you add the new scope in the manifest (appsscript.json) AND in the GCP console?  I think it has to be in both places (I believe adding it to the manifest is what should force the user re-auth).

Comment: Yes. It is in both places.

Comment: Are you running a request needing the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request scope on simple trigger?

Comment: Yes. In my manifest I am using: "gmail": { "homepageTrigger": {"enabled": true,    "runFunction": "initApp" } and within the initApp function I am executing a Jdbc.getConnection('jdbc:mysql:// call.

Comment: Can you show your complete manifest? Note: [Note: In order for a host to use the common homepage, both addOns.common.homepageTrigger and the host's top-level resource must be present in the add-on manifest. For example, if addOns.gmail isn't present in the manifest, then the add-on is disabled for Gmail and will not show a homepage (or any other functionality in that host).](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/homepages#homepage_configuration).

Comment: So ziganotschka, if I understand you I need to put both these statements into the manifest?
` "addOns": {        // ...
        "common": { // ...
          "homepageTrigger": {
            "runFunction": "initApp",
            "enabled": true},
"gmail": {
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "enabled": true,
        "runFunction": "initApp"
      }`

Comment: Yes, that's correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of hair pulling and digging, I believe I found the answer and it comes from a UI/UX issue with Google Marketplace SDK. When a new scope is added to already published Marketplace Addon on the Marketplace SDK App Configuration needs to be updated. I knew this and took care of it on 2/6 at about 2pm EST and hit save. Great, process done.... not so fast.

Errors continued in the logs through mid-day on 2/7 then stopped, but unfortunately so did new downloads volume from Marketplace, which is the trigger for the transaction. So I had no live transactions to monitor. Until 2/9, a new transaction posted and it was suddenly successful.

Because of the gap between working in the editor and not working in the deployment, my hypothesis is that there is an opaque, offline background process for Google Marketplace SDK to approve the new scopes for a published addon.

(MMQB: I probably could have been more thorough in my testing by uninstalling and reinstalling the app from test account to expose this gap, lesson learned)

Google's OAuth scope approval process is transparent as to when the new scope is pending or approved. Google Marketplace's is not. I never received any notification that an approval was pending or had been approved/rejected.

**NB:** Marketplace SDK approval is in addition to the OAuth scope approval and can't take place until the OAuth approval is complete.

Comment: I did not realize that you were adding scopes to an already published project. In this case you need to file a new request for OAuth verification before updating the Addon - to avoid the interuption - see [OAuth scope updates](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/manage-app-listing#oauth_scope_updates).